# .htaccess Rewrite Issue, One Regex for all

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### The Issue

I have written a regular expression to be used to match all of the general pages on my web application. The regular expression was working absolutely fine when the application was running on IIS with a web.config file, but I have since moved the site to a Linux server and am now running under Apache.

The strings I am trying to match are as follows:

```
section 1/
section 1/section 2/
section 1/section 2/section 3/
```

I want each match to be captured by the pattern, with the following limitations:

1. The final '/' is always optional
2. I want each match to match any character, apart from an underscore for the first two sections

This is what I have tried:

```
^([^(?!_)\/]+)\/?([^(?!_)\/]+)?\/?([^\/]+)?\/?$
```

Whilst the above works in a Regex Tester, it causes my server to produce an 'Internal Server Error' when I put it in my .htaccess file, it didn't when I ran it in my web.config.

Can anyone suggest a new pattern to use?

### Further Information

Here are a few examples of other requests:

#### Match Examples

```
test/testing
SOME/REQUEST/to a page
anything can/be matched/
```

#### Don't Match Examples

```
unless it has/an underscore_/in the/
first_section/or_second_section/
```

***Please note the 'Internal Server Error' is not being caused by other errors in my .htacess, everything works fine until I uncomment my rewrite rule with this particular regex.***

### Update

Just to be clearer, these are further examples of rewrites that I would like my regex to match:

```
http://example.com/property/
http://example.com/property.php

http://example.com/property/manage/
http://example.com/property.php?request=manage

http://example.com/property/edit/1234/
http://example.com/property.php?request=edit&id=1234

http://example.com/_property/ Does NOT Match
http://example.com/property/_edit/ Does NOT Match
```

### Update 2

The following is working but I don't like that I have specified the allowed characters:

```
^([a-z0-9\s]+)\/?([a-z0-9\s]+)?\/?([a-z0-9\s\_]+)?\/?$
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your .htaccess file? And testing on http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex matches the whole text. Maybe it is a recursion?

Comment: That is one horrible regular expression. Can you explain what you are trying to do, with examples of what should match and the desired URL to which mod-rewrite should redirect or rewrite the request?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It is a recursion, I checked the rewrite logs, the problem is, I don't know what is causing it...

Comment: @Arkanon Have I not done that in under 'Further Information'?

Comment: The expression should be fine, but question is, what does your rule look like? 500 could be caused by looping

Comment: This is nowhere a solution, but using the regex `^([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$` seems to solve the issue. Put this on your .htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$ $1.php?request=$2&id=$3` which I hope that solves the issue.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THAT REGEX!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! IT HAS A HUGE SECURITY HOLE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! SAVE YOURSELVES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!** Instead, use this one: `^(?!(?:\.\.\/?)+)([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$`

Comment: I have figured out your problem! I will post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your Regex is that it is matching it's own results.

For example:

```
http://example.com/property/
```

Will be matched as:

```
http://example.com/property.php
```

Which will be matched again by the `RewriteEngine` as:

```
http://example.com/property.php.php
```

Which will be matched as:

```
http://example.com/property.php.php.php
```

and so on...............

Solution:
Make the last slash be a must or forbid a character on the url or add an underscore (`_`) to the url.

Using your regex:

```
^([^(?!_)\/]+)\/?([^(?!_)\/]+)?\/?([^\/]+)?\/?$
```

Change it to:

```
^([^(?!_)\/]+)\/?([^(?!_)\/]+)?\/?([^\/]+)?\/$
```

As in the comments, I have proposed the following one as solving the issue:

```
^(?!(?:\.\.\/?)+)([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$
```

But it won't, but is a simplified version.
To solve this, using the solutions I have said with my Regex:

Disallowing the chars `.?`:

```
^(?!(?:\.\.\/?)+)([^_\/\.\?]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$
```

Making `\` to be a must as the last char:

```
^(?!(?:\.\.\/?)+)([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/$
```

A full redirect appending `_` to the file, in an non-obstructive hacky way (untested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:\.\.\/?)+)([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$ $1.php/_?request=$2&id=$3
```

This has the side effect of setting `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` as `_`.
This solution was **untested**!

Anything inaccurate, please leave a comment.

**Edit:**

The reasoning behind this is that we must break the matching loops.
The engine validates `http://example.com/property/` and succeeds, redirecting to `http://example.com/property.php`.
If this one matches too, all the sub-requests will match and you have recursion.
The idea is that it doesn't match `http://example.com/property.php` and continues evaluating all the other rules.

Comment: Thank you for your help, +1! :-). Which one had a 'huge security hole', and why? I am intrigued... Could we not simplify this by saying that you cannot have a '.' in any of the sections?

Comment: @BenCarey You can, but it won't help anything. Remember that filenames need `.` and you specified that **only** the `_` wasn't allowed. The security hole is that without `(?!(?:\.\.\/?)+)`, one could set the path to `../../../` and access your private stuff that souldn't be accessed over a browser.

Comment: Very good point, more reason to disallow a period. I am the one that decides the filenames in this web application, and I am certain that none of the filenames in the parent directory will ever have a period in the name, so I am happy to just disallow this...

Comment: @BenCarey You can use any of the solutions that fits you. Remember that the redirect must be changed to fit your needs. Since you want to remove the `.`, you can use this regex: `^([^_\/\.]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/$` making the whole rule as `RewriteRule ^([^_\/\.]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+)(?:\/([^_\/]+))?)?\/?$ $1.php?request=$2&id=$3`. If you use this, I recommend also disabling
 the `?` char. As a side note, you should avoid names with spaces and other special characters as they may confuse browsers and break stuff easily.

Comment: @BenCarey Just for curiosity, since you didn't said it in clear words: Did this solved the recursion issue?

Comment: Sorry Ismael, had to go into a conference. I am only concerned about disallowing characters in the first section that will prevent this rewrite from working, and/or are security flaws. In other words, I do not need to worry about disallowing spaces and other characters, as I know I will not use these in filenames etc. In fact, we could just alter the first section to just match alphanumeric characters?

Comment: This did solve the recursion issue. Dont worry, I will accept as the answer once I have ironed out these final issues :-D

Comment: @BenCarey You aren't forced to accept the answer, and I'm not asking as such. I just wanted to know if I was right or wrong. With the solution you propose, you can use the Regex `^([a-z\d]+)(?:\/([^_\/\.]+)(?:\/([^_\/\.]+))?)?\/$` for it. For this, you either set the `[NC]` flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) or set the `A-Z` range on the first group if you need uppercase letters, which I doubt. As a side effect, the period must be disallowed on the 2nd and 3rd group. But the Regex I would use is this one: `^([a-z\d]+)(?:\/([a-z\d]+)(?:\/(\d+))?)?\/$` or with \w.

Comment: Yes yes you have solved the issue, and I am very grateful!!! Especially as you pointed out a very big security flaw... I promise this will be the final run, can you make sure the last section can match anything? This is simply because this is not just an 'id', it can be a string of any characters, spaces, periods etc... It wont actually contain a periods as that would be stupid but I want it to be able to contain anything if possible? :-)

Comment: @BenCarey Sure, this is as easy as `^([a-z\d]+)(?:\/([a-z\d]+)(?:\/([^\/_\.]+))?)?\/$` which still has the restriction of not matching the `_`. If your weak spot is Regexes, I recommend using http://regex101.com/ to practice. It is a great website, as it allows to test the Regex in multiple engines and provides a detailed explanation on every aspect of the Regex. You can save them and share around too. I recommend using the JS engine, as it is the one that is closer to the .htaccess engine. I also recommend testing your .htaccess on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ before using it.

Comment: No No, I can do regex's and I use the regex101 site a lot, just not good enough to necessarily know what is the best solution in every situation... Not to mention, it is always great to have other peoples opinions to help highlight flaws like the one you spotted! :-). Thanks for all your help. I'll let you know if I have any problems.

Comment: @BenCarey I will be paying attention to the post. To help you with Regexes, I recommend that you split it into tiny pieces. And then you analise what that piece does. Then you move piece by piece. Your problem was really simple. If you have doubts in any piece, you can always test just that little bit alone. That's how I learned it. There are lots of tutorials for Regex out there, and even posts on stack overflow (link to Google: https://www.google.pt/search?q=stackoverflow+regex+learn). But any doubt regarding this issue, you can always ask at any time. And thank you for accepting my answer.